# Delete SSRS Report

Tags: ssrs-2008

I use SSRS 2008.

I need to delete some of the existing reports in my SSRS server using my script. I could not find any where about this one. The closest helpful one I could find was [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/203eeab8-9943-4282-a41a-8fda86e42aa2/rsexe-script-to-delete-from-folder-deploy) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225824(v=sql.80).aspx). Both do not tell how a report can be deleted though. My code is below. It gives me an error saying "The file could not be found".

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim bh As New BatchHeader() 

    RS.BatchHeaderValue = bh
    bh.BatchID = rs.CreateBatch()  
    RS.BatchHeaderValue = bh            

    RS.DeleteItem("/My Folder/My Report.rdl")

    Try
        RS.ExecuteBatch()
        Console.WriteLine("Removed")
    catch e As SoapException
        Console.WriteLine(e.Detail.InnerXml.ToString())
    Finally
        RS.BatchHeaderValue = Nothing
    End Try 
End Sub
```

Any helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad. I was including the ".rdl" extension. Below is the working solution.

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim bh As New BatchHeader() 

    RS.BatchHeaderValue = bh
    bh.BatchID = rs.CreateBatch()  
    RS.BatchHeaderValue = bh            

    RS.DeleteItem("/My Folder/My Report1")
    RS.DeleteItem("/My Folder/My Report2")
    RS.DeleteItem("/My Folder/My Report3")

    Try
        RS.ExecuteBatch()
        Console.WriteLine("Removed")
    catch e As SoapException
        Console.WriteLine(e.Detail.InnerXml.ToString())
    Finally
        RS.BatchHeaderValue = Nothing
    End Try 
End Sub
```